# I want to put nested type names in the first argument of setValue in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I want to do**
I want to avoid typescript error when "profile.firstName" is passed as the second argument to the function onChange.

**Error Description**
Arguments of type '"profile.firstName"' cannot be assigned to parameters of type 'keyof User'. ts(2345)

Passing "id", "groupName", and "description" as the second argument to onChange does not cause an error.
However, if "profile.firstName" is passed, an error occurs.

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import type { CustomNextPage } from 'next';

import { Button, Input } from 'components/Forms';
import { Box } from 'components/Layouts';

export interface User {
  id?: string;
  groupName?: string;
  description?: string;
  profile?: {
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    email?: string;
  };
}

const Filter: CustomNextPage = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm<User>();
  type P = keyof User;

  const onChange = (value: string, key: P) => {
    setValue(key, value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, 'id')}>ID</Input>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, 'groupName')}>GroupName</Input>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, 'description')}>Description</Input>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, 'profile.firstName')}>FirstName</Input>
        <Box>
          <form>
            <Button type="submit"></Button>
          </form>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

```
        <Input
          onChange={(e) =>
            onChange(
              {
                ...watch().profile,
                firstName: e.target.value,
              },
              'profile',
            )
          }
        >
          FirstName
        </Input>
```

Arguments of type '{ firstName: string; lastName?: string | undefined; email?: string | undefined; }' cannot be assigned to parameters of type 'string'. ts(2345)

```
        <Input
          onChange={(e) =>
            setValue(
              {
                ...watch(),
                profile: {
                  ...watch().profile,
                  firstName: e.target.value,
                },
              },
              'profile',
            )
          }
        >
          FirstName
        </Input>
```

The argument of type '{ profile: { firstName: string; lastName?: string | undefined; email?: string | undefined; }; id?: string | undefined; groupName?: string | undefined; description? undefined; description?: string | undefined; }' argument of type '"id" | "groupName" | "description" | "profile" | "profile.firstName" | "profile.lastName" | "profile.email "profile.email"' parameters cannot be assigned to parameters of type '"id" | "groupName" | "description" | "profile.firstName" | "profile.lastName" | "profile.email"'. ts(2345)

Comment: You can't access nested properties like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` has a `profile` property, which is an object that has the property `firstName`. So this approach is not going to work.

You could do something like:

```
<Input onChange={(e) => onChange({
    ...value.profile,
    firstName: e.target.value,
}, 'profile')}>FirstName</Input>
```

(I'm assuming `useForm` also returns a `value`?)

This is a little funky though. Also, `onChange.value` is no longer just a string.

---

I think you're sort of drowning in 'convenience' functions.

Maybe just do:

```
<Input onChange={(e) => setValue("profile", {
    ...value.profile,
    firstName: e.target.value,
})}>FirstName</Input>
```

And maybe just split this off to a `setProfileFirstName` funtion.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have tried to do the above but I get an error.
I have added the code.

Comment: Yea, that's what I mean `onChange.value` can no longer be just a string now. Try the 2nd code.

Comment: I also tried the second code, but it gives me an error.

Comment: Oh right, `setValue` is another convenience function. I updated the 2nd code. Does this work? This function should _not_ be called `setValue`, it should be called `setProp` or something.

Comment: Is the last 'profile' necessary?

Comment: It's not, that's a mistake.

Comment: Is there any way to get nested types like profile.firstName?